# hadoop order of lines not same in output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a text document with several sections and each section has title and body. This needs to be filtered by certain criteria and removed all junk characters in it. 
There is a problem with processing this document in map reduce as the order of lines gets jumbled in mapper output. 
So I have introduced a custom datatype linenumValuetuple and assigned a line number to each line as it is read with the text in the value so that it gets sorted by line number in reducer and key as the title id. 
But the problem is each section gets split across different mappers and single section gets different title ids. How do I make a single section as one split so that I can get the same title id for all lines and sort it in output in same order as the input ???

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create your own InputFormat and RecordReader. More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531007/creating-custom-inputformat-and-recordreader-for-binary-files-in-hadoop-mapreduc) and a  [yahoo tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#fileformat). 
The problem is that documents which span multiple block sizes get split and every split goes to a different mapper. There are certain input formats available, such as XMLInputFormat. If you could consider your input as a key-value format you could also preprocess it to SequenceFileFormat, which is ideal I think.